# Use of “for” after cost

Tags: prepositions

I wonder why “for” is not used after cost as is the case with “buy” and “sell”. I mean would it be wrong to say:

> It will cost us for $1500.

Comment: Because cost is not buy and sell.

Answer (score 3):

"$1500" is a direct object of the verb "cost".  With "buy" and "sell", the direct object is the item being bought or sold.

Comment: It might be useful to also mention how *us* is functioning in this sentence—indirect object I *think*, but I’m not actually entirely sure.

Comment: Yes, it is an indirect object.

Comment: And with "cost", the thing being bought or sold is the *subject*.